# infragistics ultramonthviewsingle runtime data bind from dataset

Tags: infragistics

I'm using Infragistics winForm. In Infragistics ultramonthviewsingle. I want to bind data at Run time from dataset. I use c#.

Comment: You might want to check out: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/51335.aspx and http://news.archive.infragistics.com/readmessage?id=%3C443c429b@mailgw.shersoft.com%3E&group=infragistics.products.netadvantage.windowsforms.winschedule

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics Schedule components expose CalendatInfo property which you can set to an instance of UltraCalendarInfo. UltraCalendarInfo holds information about all appointments, notes, users and so on. The nice thing is that you can add one calendar info, populate it with data and set it to different schedule controls.
[Here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/HTML/WinTimelineView_Appointments_DataBinding_for_WinTimelineView.html) you can find good topic showing how to populate calendar info from DataSet.